Cannot connect Pantum P2500W Laser printer to my network
The manual says my Pantum P2500W Laserjet printer supports WiFi connection, but the only way I've been able to print to it is by using the Pantum Android app.
I've tried every variation I can think of of pressing the 2 buttons on the printer and starting WPS on router via its admin interface but the router never sees the printer.

I’m voting to close this question because this is a printer/networking question, not a Unix  question

It's literally about networking, for a printer. There is no printer stack exchange

While I grant that the solution has to do with the network connection, how can the *nix user print without it? I spent many hours scouring the Internet and found no solutions to this problem as the company only documents Windows and Mac connection.

In just 2 days, the question has already garnered 3 up votes and the answer I posted below has 6. This community contains the people needing this information.

The Pantum P2500W printer supports two forms of WiFi access... "Basic Structure Mode"(normal network access) and "WiFi Direct"(a.k.a. "Soft-AP")(it looks like a router to the network). It defaults to WiFi Direct which only allows one device to connect to it at a time. This is how the Pantum Android app connects.
Thus, to print or change settings in this mode, the Android device must be disconnected from the router going to the Internet and connected to the Pantum "router" and we must do this first in order to change some settings to enable normal network access.
Once connected with the Pantum app, all settings will be visible but before they can be changed, the last tab must be chosen to login to the printer...
To enable normal network access (a.k.a. Basic Structure Mode) on the printer...

Download and install Pantum Android app
Open the app
Go to the Android device settings and turn off WiFi, then turn it on and choose
the Pantum access point shown instead of your normal router.
Go back to the app and it should connect to the printer at IP address 192.168.223.1.
Click on the tab, Login (you may have to turn the phone or other Android device sideways[landscape mode] to see the tab).
Enter the default username and password (note that the default password is also in the help text in the far right column)

Username:  admin
Password:  000000


Click on the Admin Settings tab and CHANGE THE PASSWORD

There are no other admin settings


Click on the Settings tab
In the menu on the left, select Network Settings -> Wireless Settings -> Wireless Network

Basic Status: Turn On
Search for Hotspot: Internet router SSID
Authentication...

Network Name: router SSID
Authentication: WPA/WPA2 (manual only mentions WPS)
Password: router client access password


Logout



To add the printer to Linux machine...
(I'm running running AntiX 23 so your CUPS configuration GUI may be different)

Run the CUPS GUI (system-config-printer)

Choose Add a printer
Select Device -> Network Printer -> P2500 series (printer ip address assigned by DHCP)
Host: printer ip address assigned by DHCP
Port number: 9100
Connection: AppSocket/HP JetDirect
Click the Forward button

"Searching for drivers" will popup (maybe more than once)


Choose Driver

Scroll down and select Pantum
Models: P2500W
Drivers: Pantum P2500 series, driverless, cups-filters 1.28.17 en (recommended)


Click the Forward button
Complete the three Describe Printer fields as desired and click the Apply button



